# Setting GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH crashes Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

So I have a model of a WAM Arm.  I wrote a plugin that moves its joints through a list of joint positions.

When I:

- don't have the `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH` set
- cd into the directory of the model
- then run Gazebo

I can insert the model from the "insert" menu. It then executes the joint movements.

If I try running Gazebo from outside that directory, I can still insert the model, but it won't go through the movements.

Then, if I try setting the `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH` to the model directory, inserting the model results in an errorless crash.

Any thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2633/setting-gazebo_plugin_path-crashes-gazebo/) by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 175 on 2013-04-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-01**:
You may also need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the model directory as well. Can you try that?

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-05-01**:
I still have both problems:  The plugin isn't found when I launch Gazebo from outside of the model/plugin directory.  Also, Gazebo still crashed when I set the GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-01**:
Can you get a backtrace of the crash using gdb? `gdb gzserver` in one terminal, gzclient in another, and then insert the model. If it crashes, then `bt` in the gdb terminal.

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-05-02**:
Thanks for the help, scpeters.  In the end, the problem was my fault. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In case this happens to anyone else:

The plugin was designed to read in a list of joint coordinates from a file. The file was placed in the same directory as the SDF file.

So: When I ran Gazebo from the directory containing the model & plugin, it found the plugin and found the joint file. No problem.

When I ran Gazebo from outside of the directory without the `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH` set, it wouldn't find the plugin, and it handled that gracefully by inserting the model, not running the plugin and giving me a "plugin not found" message.

When I ran Gazebo from outside of the directory with the `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH` set, it found the plugin, but the plugin couldn't find the joint file and segfaulted.  This brought Gazebo down with it.

Solution: In the plugin code: Use an absolute file path instead of a file path that was relative to the plugin.  Or, in the plugin code, handle missing joint files more gracefully.

---

Originally posted by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) with karma: 175 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-03**:
Can you clarify which environment variables you set? I don't think GAZEBO_MODEL_PLUGIN is right.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-03**:
Also, if you want to store additional files in your model directory, you can find them using [gazebo::common::SystemPaths::FindFileURI()](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1common_1_1SystemPaths.html) with the uri "model://model_name/path/to/file"

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-03**:
Also, if you want to store additional files in your model directory, you can find them using [gazebo::common::SystemPaths::FindFileURI()](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1common_1_1SystemPaths.html) with the uri "model://model_name/path/to/file"

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-05-03**:
Right you are :)  I meant `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH`.   Thanks for the tip on FindFileURI!

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-05-03**:
Actually, I'm a bit confused how to use this.  SystemPaths is a class, right?  So I try to instantiate an object inside the load function of my plugin : `common::SystemPaths sys_path_obj;`  and then I get the error: `/usr/include/gazebo-1.7/gazebo/common/SystemPaths.hh:60:16: error: ‘gazebo::common::SystemPaths::SystemPaths()’ is private`.  Is that telling me the constructor is private?

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-03**:
You don't need to instantiate that class; you should be able to just call the gazebo::common::SystemPaths::FindFileURI(), as long as you have the header included.

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-05-03**:
Doing this:  `std::string pathy =  gazebo::common::SystemPaths::FindFileURI("model://WAM Model/forGazebo");`

gives `/home/benjaminblumer/.../set_joints.cc: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::SetJoints::Load(gazebo::physics::ModelPtr, sdf::ElementPtr)’: /home/benjaminblumer/.../plugins/set_joints.cc:49:99: error: cannot call member function ‘std::string gazebo::common::SystemPaths::FindFileURI(const string&)’ without object`

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-05-03**:
And I'm including the common/common.hh header.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-03**:
My apologies, based on [ModelDatabase.cc:396](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/8797fa1494625c63871107d5a38f40da33f1ec58/gazebo/common/ModelDatabase.cc?at=default#cl-396), you should use `gazebo::common::SystemPaths::Instance()->FindFileURI()`.

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-05-03**:
Ah. That works great.  Thanks, SC.